# PowerShell - Invoke-RestMethod return partial response

Tags: powershell, invoke-restmethod

I'm running a GET Rest request using PowerShell *Invoke-RestMethod* command.
When trying to run the same API on a browser, I'm getting a full JSON file with full content.
But when running using PowerShell *Invoke-RestMethod*, some parameters are not full. Instead I see: `System.Object[]`.
For Example:

```
"process":  {
                    "phases":  [
                                   "@{steps=System.Object[]; name=Agent job 1; refName=Job_1;
```

What I'm expecting to get is:

```
"process": {
        "phases": [
            {
                "steps": [
                    {
                        "environment": {},
                        "enabled": true,
                        "continueOnError": false,
                        "alwaysRun": false,
```

Does any one have an idea how to overcome this PowerShell limitation?

Thanks,
Shai.

Comment: Looks like it is related to the Depth parameter of the convertto/convertfrom json.
Did you try using something like this ?
(Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri 'xxxxx').Content | convertto-json -depth 10